# Breaking the span's text by ", "

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `<span>` which contains a list of skills separated by a comma and a space. Now with jQuery or with CSS (if possible) I would like to get only the skills without the `", "`.

So if I have the skills like: `Photographer, Designer`

I need to separate those skills and store each skill in an JavaScript array.

Comment: What have you attempted to solve this problem?

Comment: This has been answered sooooo many times already

Comment: You can use the jQuery `replace` function. Similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7842875/removing-comma-for-value-with-javascript

Comment: I love the fact that your profile says that you are a web developer (MS specialist) but you haven't even heard of a split function. I mean come on, if you really know PHP, C, C++ you would have thought about searching for the equivalent split function in JS!

Comment: @DanyKhalife I love the fact that you read his profile but didn't notice his age ;-) Considering his tender age, I would ignore all the skills I read on that profile.

Comment: well young or not, if he had the time to fill in his profile he also had the time to do a bit of searching before posting, if not on SO maybe on google there are LOTS of web tutorials out there it only takes 1 word for him to type...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given this markup

```
<span id="skills">Skill1, Skill2, Skill3</span>
```

You could use the `split()` method

```
$('#skills').text().split(', ');  // ["Skill1", "Skill2", "Skill3"]
```

Answer (score 3):

use the Javascript function `split`

```
var str = $("span").text();
var results = str.split(", ");
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Comment: Get ready to be slated for referencing w3schools, by people that never back up their argument.

Comment: use the Javascript function, but you use the $ from Jquery instead of document.getElementByXXX depending on the need.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to remove spaces as well then

```
"Photographer, Designer, Wedding Planners".split(',').map(function(){return arguments[0].replace(/^(\s)*/g, '')});
```

or else you can simply use

```
"Photographer, Designer".split(',');
```

Comment: The problem with removing spaces first is that you remove spaces in between skills, like "Wedding Planning". You probably don't want that.

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that before posting the answer. Updated it now

Answer (score 0):

Use split :

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

```
var skill = "Photgrapher, Designer";
var skillArray = skill.split(", ");
console.log(skillArray); // output ["Photographer", "Designer"]
```

Answer (score 0):

user javascript `split` function it will return a `array`

Code like this :

```
<span>Photographer, Designer</span>

var str = $("span").text();
var results = str.split(", ");
```

you can use this as `results[0]` , `results[1]`

I Hope it will help.